# Can I put hash as the first parameter in method?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby, and I encounter an problem.

This is the code I wrote.

```
class Customer
  def puts_result(name, addr)
    return name, addr
  end
end

aaron = Customer.new
puts aaron.puts_result "Aaron", {country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"}
puts aaron.puts_result "Aaron", country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"
puts aaron.puts_result {country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"}, "Aaron"
```

I call the puts_result method and pass the parameters through three different ways.

In the first way, I passed the hash with curly braces, and it works fine.
In the second way, I passed the hash without curly braces, and it stills works fined.

What I problem is in the third way, I passed the hash as the first parameter with curly braces, but it returns an error.

> (repl):15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' puts
>   aaron.puts_result {country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"}, "Aaron"
>   (repl):15: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}' puts aaron.puts_result {country: "Taiwan", city:
>   "Tainan"}, "Aaron"

Is there something my carelessness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occures in your third call

```
puts aaron.puts_result {country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"}, "Aaron"
```

Here, there is a syntax ambiguity when parsing the opening curly brace. It could either be the start of a Hash (which is what you intend) or the beginning of a block passed to the method.

Ruby's parser always assumes that an opening brace after a method signals the start of a block unless you put the argument in explicit parenthesis. This would then resolve the ambiguity since a block is never declared inside the parenthesis but always outside.

With your code, you can thus resolve the ambiguity as follows:

```
puts aaron.puts_result({country: "Taiwan", city: "Tainan"}, "Aaron")
```

To get a repeatable rule from this: always remember to use paranthesis around method calls when the first argument is a literal hash with braces.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the explanation very much.